# Where should I put the 'return m' statement in order to return the position of element in the following binary search function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, return, binary-search

I'm pretty new to programming and python. When I run the following script, I can tell by the output of the `print` statements that the function has correctly identified the position of the element in a user-defined sorted list, but when I return the value into a variable, the value changes to another value.What am I doing wrong? Is it the placement of the `return` statement?

```
#
#       Binary Search Function
#       Arguments-listx:Pre Sorted List upon which alogrithm works
#                 term :The term to be located in list
#                 l    :Lower limit of Range
#                 r    :Upper Limit of Range
#                 m    :Mid Point of Range
#       Ideally returns the location of the term in the list

def binsearch(listx, term, l, r, m):
    print(m,",",listx[m])
    if listx[m] != term:
        if listx[m] < term:
            l = m + 1
            m = (l + r) // 2
            binsearch(listx, term, l, r, m)
        if listx[m] > term:
            r = m - 111
            m = (l + r) // 2
            binsearch(listx, term, l, r, m)
    return m
```

Comment: You need to `return` the result of each `binsearch()` call.  That means that each line that calls `binsearch()` should have `return` at the beginning.

Comment: you mean replace them with return(binsearch(listx, term, l, r, m)) ?

Comment: Well, the parentheses are useless.  I would say `return binsearch(listx, term, l, r, m)`, but yes.